# How can I masked input for React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm working a project for React.js. How do I mask IP addresses? I'm using react-maskedinput npm package. Can you help me?

```js
<MaskedInput
  mask="111.111.111.111"
  name="card"
  size="20"
  formatCharacters={{
    'W': {
      validate(char) { return /\w/.test(char ) },
      transform(char) { return char.toUpperCase() }
     }
    }
  }
/>
```

Thanks,
Emre.

Comment: Here is almost your case → http://insin.github.io/react-maskedinput/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From reading the docs (https://github.com/insin/react-maskedinput), it seems as if you don't need the `formatCharacters` props (unless you special masking needs). Try this:

```
<MaskedInput
  mask="111.111.111.111"
  name="card"
  size="20"/>
```

Comment: I could not tell the exact problem. I want to make a ip masked like this one. https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/